# Fonts not loading after changing of the configuration file in Angular Project

Tags: angular

I have some CSS file that I included in the angular.json file in which the profiles for the builds are defined. So that the whole app has those files. 
The CSS it self loads but for some odd reason the fonts that are referenced in the CSS files don't load. 
And I have no clue as to why this is happening.
The reason why I think that that json file is the problem is because after it was changed the fonts stopped loading.

Here is the whole configuration file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frdemo-front-end": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/demo/S/S/S/insure/",
            "polyfills": "target/frdemo/ng/polyfills.ts",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/css/common-layout-ng.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/css/funnels.css"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production-fr": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "src": "target/frdemo/ng/environments/environment.ts",
                  "replaceWith": "target/frdemo/ng/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "index": "target/frdemo/ng/app/insure/index.html",
              "main": "target/frdemo/ng/app/insure/frdemo-policy-manager-root/frdemo-policy-manager-root.main.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/insure/tsconfig.in.prod.json",
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "aot": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "outputPath": "target/frdemo/ng/dist/fr",
              "i18nLocale": "fr"
            },
            "production-en": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "src": "target/frdemo/ng/environments/environment.ts",
                  "replaceWith": "target/frdemo/ng/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "index": "target/frdemo/ng/app/insure/index.html",
              "main": "target/frdemo/ng/app/insure/frdemo-policy-manager-root/frdemo-policy-manager-root.main.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/insure/tsconfig.in.prod.json",
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "aot": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "outputPath": "target/frdemo/ng/dist/en",
              "i18nLocale": "en",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nFile": "target/frdemo/ng/locale/messages.en.xlf",
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "ignore"
            },
            "en": {
              "index": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/insure/index.html",
              "main": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/insure/frdemo-policy-manager-root/frdemo-policy-manager-root.main.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/insure/tsconfig.in.dev.json",
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "outputPath": "target/frdemo/ng/dist/en",
              "i18nLocale": "en",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nFile": "src/main/webapp/ng/locale/messages.en.xlf",
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "ignore"
            },
            "fr": {
              "index": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/insure/index.html",
              "main": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/insure/frdemo-policy-manager-root/frdemo-policy-manager-root.main.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/insure/tsconfig.in.dev.json",
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "outputPath": "target/frdemo/ng/dist/fr",
              "i18nLocale": "fr"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frdemo-front-end:build:production-en"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "demo-frauto-wc": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": "target/frdemo/ng/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig-wc.json",
            "extractCss": true,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "outputPath": "target/frdemo/ng/dist/wc",
            "index": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/web-component/demo-frauto-wc/proposal/index.html",
            "main": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/web-component/demo-frauto-wc/proposal/demo-frauto-wc.main.ts",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/normalize.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/common.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/components.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/funnel.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/style-pi-core.css"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/document-register-element/build/document-register-element.js"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/main/webapp/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              }
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production-fr": {
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "aot": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "i18nLocale": "fr",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "src": "src/main/webapp/ng/environments/environment.ts",
                  "replaceWith": "src/main/webapp/ng/environments/environment.wc-prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "fr": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "src": "src/main/webapp/ng/environments/environment.ts",
                  "replaceWith": "src/main/webapp/ng/environments/environment.wc-prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "i18nLocale": "fr"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo-frauto-wc:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production-fr": {
              "browserTarget": "demo-frauto-wc:build:production-fr"
            },
            "fr": {
              "browserTarget": "demo-frauto-wc:build:fr"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "client-space": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/demo/S/S/S/web-insure/",
            "polyfills": "target/frdemo/ng/polyfills.ts",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/css/common-layout-ng.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/css/funnels.css"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production-fr": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "src": "target/frdemo/ng/environments/environment.ts",
                  "replaceWith": "target/frdemo/ng/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "index": "target/frdemo/ng/app/web-insure/index.html",
              "main": "target/frdemo/ng/app/web-insure/frdemo-policy-client-root/frdemo-policy-client-root.main.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/web-insure/tsconfig.wi.prod.json",
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "aot": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "outputPath": "target/frdemo/ng/dist/wi/fr",
              "i18nLocale": "fr"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "web-space": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/demo/S/S/S/web-insure-quote/",
            "polyfills": "target/frdemo/ng/polyfills.ts",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/normalize.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/common.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/components.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/funnel.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "target/frdemo/ng/app/business-frdemo/frdemo-client-side/css/style-pi-core.css"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [
              {
                "input": "src/main/webapp/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              }
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production-fr": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "src": "target/frdemo/ng/environments/environment.ts",
                  "replaceWith": "target/frdemo/ng/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "index": "target/frdemo/ng/app/web-insure-quote/index.html",
              "main": "target/frdemo/ng/app/web-insure-quote/frdemo-policy-web-root/frdemo-policy-web-root.main.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/main/webapp/ng/app/web-insure-quote/tsconfig.wiq.prod.json",
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "aot": false,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "outputPath": "target/frdemo/ng/dist/wc/fr",
              "i18nLocale": "fr"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The CSS files in question are all in "frdemo-client-side", the fonts are in the folder under "fnt" folder and the CSS files are in the folder "css".

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + R to hard reload the page or restart the server.

Comment: I tried all that, clearing the cache and all. But the fonts just don't load. The weirdest thing that the part that has the css files has nothing to do with the part that was changed. Still it stopped loading after the other part changed.